# Sef URL CSS Problems

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I try to create Search Engine Friendly URLS  like this;:

```
RewriteRule ^m/([0-9]+)$ my.php?id=$1
```

However, it gets the page without CSS.

If I write like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ my.php?id=$1
```

it gets the page with CSS without any problem.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Was my answer not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write CSS references like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

it's a relative URL. On `http://example.com/`, that points to `http://example.com/style.css`, but on `http://example.com/my/1` it points to `http://example.com/my/style.css`, which doesn't exist.

Using an absolute URL fixes this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by adding a `base` attribute to the head tag of each page:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

or add `/` before the css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheet.css">
```

What was happening was that when you were redirecting the page, it was also looking for the css in `my/css` instead of `css` adding  the above will fix that.